# My program has hang and I dont know how to fix it for now

Tags: java, multithreading

This is a part of my program. I am convinced that this class is where my code is getting hung up. I am using deadlock thread in `java` and I have difficulties.

So I did not want to display my entire code but this is a sample. Can someone tell me why it is hanging? this deadlock situation is confusing me.

```
public class gameEnemyRelease {
       private static Object enemy1 = new Object();
       public static Object enemy2= new Object();

       public static void main(String args[]) {

          player1 p1 = new player1();
          player2 p2 = new player2();
         p1.start();
          p2.start();
       }

       private static class player1 extends Thread {
          public void run() {
             synchronized (enemy1) {
                System.out.println("Start Launch");
                try { Thread.sleep(10); }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                System.out.println("Waiting for enemy 2 to launch...");
                synchronized (enemy2) {
                   System.out.println("Shot");
                }
             }
          }
       }
       private static class player2 extends Thread {
          public void run() {
             synchronized (enemy2) {
                System.out.println("...");
                try { Thread.sleep(10); }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                System.out.println("");
                synchronized (enemy1) {
                   System.out.println("");
                }
             }
          }
       } 
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have read this. I just want some help on why my code is hanging.

Comment: you're locking in exactly opposite order in both threads. let's say both are executing, they both lock the appropriate enemyX. now `player2` owns `enemy2`, and `player1` owns `enemy1`, so then the synched println's come up, they can't be executed, because the OTHER thread owns that lock, so they both wait for each other to release the locks, which they can't. `player2` tries to do `enemy1`, but has to wait for `player1`. and player1 is doing the exact same thing with enemy2

Comment: Thank you everyone, i bet all programmers must go through that simple bug which doesnt want to go away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your program is hanging probably  because neither of the threads in position to proceed and waiting for each other to release the lock. So you can try changing this method; Try the below code:

```
private static class player2 extends Thread {
          public void run() {
             synchronized (enemy1) {
                System.out.println("...");
                try { Thread.sleep(10); }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                System.out.println("");
                synchronized (enemy2) {
                   System.out.println("");
                }
             }
```

Answer (score 4):

Think about this code path:

- Thread 1 locks Enemy 1
- Thread 2 locks Enemy 2
- Threads 1 try to lock Enemy 2 but is locked by thread 2, so it waits
- Thred 2 try to lock Enemy 1  but is locked by thread 1, so it waits

You need to address and probably lock both enemies from start.